# Mt5 language translation - Language in parameters

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model, machine-translation, huggingface

I'm trying to train a Arabic to English language translation model, and want to know if there is any option where I can mention the input and target language in the code.

I'm using the below code, where df1 is the dataframe with columns (prefix,input_text,target_text)

```
from simpletransformers.t5 import T5Model, T5Args
model = T5Model("mt5", "google/mt5-small", args=model_args, use_cuda=False)
model.train_model(df1,eval_data=df2)
results = model.eval_model(df2, verbose=True)
```